# Multiple loops on a Search result page?

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom template that displays search results based on a plugin. The wp_query contains all the taxonomy information to show the proper posts.

How can I have two loops on the same results page? The first would contain posts from the query with the taxonomy of `ptype` and the term `featured`.

The second loop contains all the rest of the posts from the main query EXCEPT the ones with the taxonomy of `ptype` and the term `featured`.

When the posts are queried they are queried through two other custom taxonomies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) function. You'll be able to run multiple queries and get an array for each post type